# Alarming potions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

[Alchemists formulae](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/formulae-lists---alchemist) includes [Invisibility Alarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility-alarm).

Does that mean they can actually create a potion of alarm? How does that work? When you drink the potion do you then choose where the alarm spell takes effect? It just doesn't seem to make any sense that you drink a potion to create the alarm effect. Have I misunderstood the meaning of the formula or is that really how it works?

Most other potions amplify the person drinking them somehow, which makes sense. The alarm spell though has a separate external target that is not the person drinking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Extracts are the most varied of the three. In many ways, they behave like spells in potion form, and as such their effects can be dispelled by effects like dispel magic using the alchemist's level as the caster level. Unlike potions, though, extracts can have powerful effects and duplicate spells that a potion normally could not.
>
> ...
>
> An extract is “cast” by drinking it, as if imbibing a potion—the effects of an extract exactly duplicate the spell upon which its formula is based, save that the spell always affects only the drinking alchemist.

Alarm is not on the formulae list but Invisibility Alarm is. Its effect is "Area: 20-ft.-radius emanation centered on a point in space." Per the general extract rules its effect is changed to be an emanation from the alchemist instead of from "a point in space." Many of the other personal spells on the formula list are emanations or similar centered on a person, where the alchemist is subbed in for the source not the entire "emanation from" line - cf. the Detect spells, magnetic field, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I could find in the formulae was Invisibility Alarm, but since that functions as Alarm for a number of features, it should apply.

[Alarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alarm) creates a 20 ft radius emanation based on a single point. If a potion would be created, it would be centered on the drinker. If a creature of sufficient size came within 20-ft of the drinker, then the alarm would alert the drinker.

Comment: Yes, that's the best conclusion I was able to come to too but it still leaves a lot unanswered. For example if the person moves then by the way alarm works the alarm would not move. If the person has drunk the potion and is the target though does the alarm now move with them?

Comment: @TimB Effect moves with her....? It would be like any other aura.

Answer (score 0):

From the feat ["Brew Potion"](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation---final):

> You can create a potion of any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures or objects.

Alarm (and Invisibility Alarm) don't have targets, and therefore cannot be made into potions.

Unless you were thinking of extracts not potions, in which case it just works, because magic (well, pseudo-magic, but still).